# No equals method when deploying and running JBoss

Tags: jboss, equals

I have class equals and hashcode

```
public class ObjectType {
...
```

In Eclipse outline view equals and hashcode methods are visible.

At runtime i get exception at JBoss 4.2.3.GA:

```
 12:21:58,741 ERROR [STDERR] Exception in thread "Thread-29"
 12:21:58,741 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: core.notdb.ObjectType.equals(Lcom/alt1/cbc/core/notdb/ObjectType;)Z
```

for code:

```
@Override
public Entity getEntity(ObjectType objectType, Object id) {
        if (BaseStationSubsystem.getBscObjectType().equals(objectType)) {
```

Comment: Why did you put lombok.jar in the lib dir? Lombok currently does not need any runtime dependencies. Full Disclosure: I am one of the Project Lombok developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly class compiled with another java version setting was deployed with other classes compiled with second java version setting.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the method `ObjectType#equals(ObjectType other)` is called from JBoss instead of `ObjectType#equals(Object other)`. Lombok correctly only generates the latter one.

Full Disclosure: I am one of the [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) developers.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is related to Lombok for now.

Comment: Lombok unrelated. Deleting tag. See answer below.